# Using Regex to catch text until first occurrence of certain character

Tags: python, regex

Consider I have the following text:
`Temp:C5E501374D0343090957F7E5929E765C931F7D3EC7A96189FDA88549D54D9E4E5DB3FC1C2, adfsafd1242412,`

And I want to catch all the data after `Temp:` and until first occurrence of `,` which means: `C5E501374D0343090957F7E5929E765C931F7D3EC7A96189FDA88549D54D9E4E5DB3FC1C2`

I tried using regex `Temp:(.+,)` without success
How do I tell the regex that `,` should be the first found?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To capture the value you need, you could try and [use lazy matching dot](https://regex101.com/r/cR3nR6/1) (`.+?` matches 1 or more characters - but as few as possible - that are any characters but a newline):

```
Temp:(.+?),
```

Since lazy matching might eat up more than you need, a [negated character class](https://regex101.com/r/cR3nR6/2) (`[^,]+` matches 1 or more characters other than a comma) looks preferable:

```
Temp:([^,]+)
```

The result is captured into Group 1 with the capturing group (parentheses).

[IDEONE sample code](http://ideone.com/PTN1dZ):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'Temp:([^,]+)')
test_str = "Temp:C5E501374D0343090957F7E5929E765C931F7D3EC7A96189FDA88549D54D9E4E5DB3FC1C2, adfsafd1242412,"
print (re.search(p, test_str).group(1))
```

Output: `C5E501374D0343090957F7E5929E765C931F7D3EC7A96189FDA88549D54D9E4E5DB3FC1C2`

**NOTE** that a look-around based solution is more resource-consuming that the capturing group one that you and I are using.

Comment: The negated character class is the right way of doing it. Using a Lazy Quantifier on `.+` might not work correctly under *certain* circumstances. (`(.+?),` *can* match a `,` with the `.`, if the rest of the pattern could only be matched when doing so -> Greediness of Regex Engine)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this lookbehind based regex:

```
(?<=Temp:)[^,]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN4rN3/3)

**Code**:

```
s='Temp:C5E501374D0343090957F7E5929E765C931F7D3EC7A96189FDA88549D54D9E4E5DB3FC1C2, adfsafd1242412,'
print re.search(r"(?<=Temp:)[^,]+", s).group()
```

**Output:**

```
C5E501374D0343090957F7E5929E765C931F7D3EC7A96189FDA88549D54D9E4E5DB3FC1C2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `?` character to make the `+` ungreedy. Otherwise all the `,` characters also match with the `.+` part of the regex. In my answer I moved the `,` outside of the group since from your description I understood that you actually didn't want it in the match.

```
import re
matcher = re.compile("Temp:(.+?),")
matcher.match(a).group(1)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you use compile and not `re.search` for instance?

Comment: @JavaSa I used compile in order to get a RegexObject which can later on be used for matching. I tend to assume that a regex is going to be used repeatedly. In theory the objects are cached internally by re and this isn't a requirement, but I favor explicit solutions from implicit ones and I find keeping RegexObjects to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp: `Temp:([^,]+,)`

Now, anything after `Temp:` is included until the first `,`.